# Find textbox in gridview in JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have a gridview which contains image buttons. On click of that image button, another grid gets filled which contains some textboxes. I want to fire JQuery validation for those textboxes on lost focus if the value inserted in textbox is greater than one of the column value of gridview. That column value is using bound field to bind data.

How can I achieve this using Jquery? I am new in JQuery.

I have tried something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {

        var GridView = $('#grdSalesOrder tr').each(function () {
            var btn = $(this).find('img[id*=imgdesign1]');
            alert(btn);
        });

    });
</script>
```

First I am finding the main gridview and imagebutton of that grid view. When button is clicked, another gridview gets filled. So i think I should write code to find another grid on click event of this image button because at the time of page load event, another grid will not be available. But in this code I am not getting the button which is there in main grid view. Plz edit my Jquery if I am making any mistake.

Comment: show the html code ... or try jQuery.com

Comment: @Dileep Dil..html code is too large to paste here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some JQuery you can configure to meet your needs.

It assumes you have added a CssClass to your grid view like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Products" runat="server" CssClass="grid_view">
```

A CssClass to your text boxes like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserInput runat="server" CssClass="user_input" />
```

And that the column value that is bound is in your header row.

So if your html table output from your grid view is similar to this

```
<table class="grid_view" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Products" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">12</th><th scope="col">4</th><th scope="col">21</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td><td>1</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td><td>1</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td><td>1</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td><td>1</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="user_input" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user_input" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="user_input" /></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

You can use this JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.user_input').blur(function() {
    var enteredVal = $(this).val();
    var currentCell = $(this).closest("td");

    col = $(currentCell).prevAll().length;
    var obj = $(this).parents('table').find('th').eq(col);
    var hrVal = obj.text();

    // your validation here
    if (parseInt(enteredVal,10) > parseInt(hrVal,10)) {
        alert('too big');
    }
});​
</script>
```

​
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicholas_Murray/Sr9H9/2/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is how to find each element you wish on your grid. With out html code, I can give you some hits to start.

This code is select all your textbox inside your GridView with id YourGridViewID

```
jQuery('#<%=YourGridViewID.ClientID%> input[type=text]')
```

To add the lost focus you set

```
jQuery('#<%=YourGridViewID.ClientID%> input[type=text]').blur{
    // add the code for the validation
});
```

Now if you write one two lines from your grid maybe I can help you more to locate the other data.

Comment: @Aristos..I have edited my question. Please review it once again.